# Collapsible seems to be working, however, content not being shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website to serve as a hub for all my creative content. I am doing this for a project and I have been following random tutorials to get to where I am. Currently, I am stumped as a collapsible section I am trying to implement is *sort of* working. In the sense, that when I click the + changes to a - showing the click is being registered. However, the content does not expand, it remains hidden.

HTML code in question:

```
<section>

<button type="button" class="collapsible"><h5>Click Here to View Entire YouTube Library!</h5></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...ALLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL</p>
</div>   
<script src="collapsible.js"></script>
</section>
```

JavaScript being used:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Relates css in case it is required:

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #272727;
}
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

Please keep in mind, I am a newbie following tutorials so I won't have deep understanding of the topic yet. Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is wrong styling manipulation, the reason element doesn't appear is because of `overflow` and not `display`, `display` is either `block` or `inline` by default (depends on the element). Edit your Javascript code like below:

```
    if (content.style.overflow === "visible") {
      content.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      content.style.overflow = "visible";
    }
```

You have explicitly set `overflow: hidden`, so that's why changing the display doesn't work.